# Module level sitemap generation in angular

Tags: angular, sitemap

My site as multiple modules. Each module have multiple routes.

I could able to generate root level sitemap.

But I got no idea on how to generate sitemap for each module.

```
Root - www.example.com/sitemap.xml - Works fine
 -ModuleA - www.example.com/ModuleA/sitemap.xml - No idea how to make this happen
 -ModuleB - www.example.com/ModuleB/sitemap.xml
 -ModuleC - www.example.com/ModuleC/sitemap.xml.
```

So I've I enter this url, `ww.example.com/ModuleA/sitemap.xml` I should able to see the sitemap.

Also, Sitemap should be generated while loading the module.

Comment: Are you working on angular universal for server side rendering?

Comment: yes, my app is ssr enabled

Comment: hello friend i have a similar problem, did you find any solution? @stacknew